# Converting PHP website to Android App (APK) with Android Studio

Tags: php, android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I wanted to have an android app for my website but since I am not an android developer I went on to find a solution if there was a way I could convert my website to an android app. Then I quickly got over a video which showed how to convert a PHP website to an android app (apk) using Android Studio. The video was published back in 2016 but still seems like that would work. However, my concern is that will a PHP converted android app be reliable enough for a large scale application? Suppose I have a social network kind of website but I don't have enough funds in the business to hire an android developer to code my app right now (maybe in future if the business grows we can go for it), so will the PHP converted app be reliable? Will it work as good as native java coded android app? Or not? Any suggestions are excepted as well. :)

Link to video I found: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AnHWVbK323A

Comment: `PHP converted android app` you should not try to convert cocial network into the app, as it will become *unsocial*. There is no way to just convert it. Max what you can do is to open your website in the WebView, which is bad thing, as you always can use the web browser for that. Don't expect it to be as reliable as native app.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I carried on with the research and finally got an amazing answer to my question. I found the following page and to my surprise I found those big apps to be hybrid which I never even imagined would be. Twitter, Instagram and Uber are the best example. They are big but ain't native. They all are hybrid. Now I am confident to have my app hybrid rather than going for a native one. More information here https://blog.venturepact.com/8-high-performance-apps-you-never-knew-were-hybrid/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you'd be able to directly convert your PHP code to an android app.
you can use a webview (something like what chrome does )and show your website.
or you can release an API or some sort of JSON output and analyze those data with an app(like what Instagram does).

Answer (score 0):

There is no conversion involved, he just loads his website into a webview.
This is good for a 'first-app', to understand the android studio flow, from writing code to compilation.
But in the real life it doesn't make sense, because the mobile browser is already a webview. So you better invitate your mobile users to navigate directly on your site rather than forcing them to install an app that will open your site into it.

Comment: What I feel like (correct me if I am wrong) is that people now-a-days are more comfortable opening an app by just tapping it once rather than open a browser and typing the URL to access it. Before when facebook was newly launched people didn't have access so much to smartphones and had to use desktop to open the site. But now they have become more deemed to towards mobile app (most in case of social network) like facebook, messenger, tinder etc. Downloading just once and one tap open forever. So, that's why I wanted to make an app rather than forcing them to open in mobile browser(s).

Comment: What's your take on this?

Comment: To me, apps market is saturated + smartphones are overloaded with tons of apps people are not using anymore. If your app is doing nothing else than opening your site, it may probably end as it.
I believe it depends also of your service. But Facebook, Tinder, Messenger and so, all went app to improve their services and because most of them are smartphone apps by nature.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this useful question, as many of newbie developers and some curious peoples trying to know best way to convert their website into android app.
I have suggestions as follows:
1st: try flutter for your website as it is popular and flexible for cross platform development and has many features.
If your website is in flutter ,you can create your app for both android and ios using just one command.

2nd: develop an android app according to your website and connect it to your database using volley, RestApi or many others. It is easier and popular way.

I hope you'll find both ways better than using a webview cause it's not what you want.

You can also ask me for further help.
Thank you.